# How to build jsonpath expression for checking the number of times in array?

Tags: java, jsonpath, json-path-expression, jayway

Suppose I have a json like this 
{
"city" :[
"Bangalore",
"Delhi",
"Chennai",
"Bangalore"
]
}
Now I want to make a make a json path query to check if bangalore is occuring twice or not so to check that I want to extract no of times Bangalore is coming in array so how can we build the jsonpath expression?

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If it did please accept it as the right answer, otherwise please add a comment why not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you are asking but I guess you are using jayway's jsonpath library in java. In that case you can probably use this:

```
int amountOfBangalore = JsonPath.parse(json).read("$.city.[?(@ == \"Bangalore\")]").length();
```

Where you construct a list filled with each instance of 'bangalore' in the text and then call length() on that.